# Dynamically Selecting Records Based on User Input Table Name

Tags: sql, oracle

Description: I have a scenario where I need to select all records from a table specified by the user. I have a query in mind, but I need assistance to ensure it's correctly implemented. Here's what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM user_tables 
    WHERE table_name = (SELECT '&table_name' FROM dual)
);
```

I want to prompt the user to enter a table name, and based on their input, dynamically select all records from that table. Could someone review my query and suggest any improvements or corrections? Thanks!

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. You need to show source tables and data, the result you want to achieve based on that data, the SQL you’ve managed to write and an explanation of what the issue is

Comment: This is first query:

SELECT
        *
    FROM
        HR.EMPLOYEES;

i want to fetch same result using below query

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM user_tables 
    WHERE table_name = (SELECT '&table_name' FROM dual)
);

but it give me only table name

Comment: I'm still not clear what SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES has to do with the other query, what the result is that you are trying to achieve or what the issue is that you are facing. However, your first query is just going to select table_name as that is the only column in the inner query you are selecting from. In fact the outer query is pointless as it's just selecting what the inner query returns, so you may as well just have the inner query

Comment: I have a scenario where I need to select all records from a table specified by the user. I have a query in mind, but I need assistance to ensure it's correctly implemented. Here's what I have so far:

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM user_tables 
    WHERE table_name = (SELECT '&table_name' FROM dual)
);

I want to prompt the user to enter a table name, and based on their input, dynamically select all records from that table. Could you review my query and suggest any improvements or corrections? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL i.e. get the table name from the user, construct the SQL statement string you want to execute (including the table name) - probably using concatenation - and then execute that statement

Answer (score 2):

As it seems that you're selecting all (`*`) columns from table passed as a parameter, a simple option is to create a function that returns refcursor. Here's an example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tab (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN rc FOR 'select * from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name);
  7
  8     RETURN rc;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_tab ('dept') FROM DUAL;

F_TAB('DEPT')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Another table:

```
SQL> SELECT f_tab ('emp') FROM DUAL;

F_TAB('EMP')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30

14 rows selected.


SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Substitution variables `&variable_name` are supported by the client application you are using to connect to the database (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLCl and some others, but not all clients) - they are not supported by the Oracle database.

What happens is the client application uses a pre-processor that parses the query (before it gets sent to the database) and sees something that matches the substitution variable syntax and asks the user what to replace the substitution variable with. The client application then effectively performs a find-replace on the query and substitutes the substitution variable with the user-provided text and then sends that modified query to the database. The database never sees the original query.

If you are using a client application that supports substitution variables then you can simply use:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   &table_name;
```

The user will be prompted what to replace `&table_name` with and then the database will run the query. There will be no checks that the query is valid or that the user has not selected from multiple tables, etc. If the modified query is syntactically valid then the database will try to execute it.

*Note: I would usually bring up the concept of SQL injection attacks; however, your entire question is about allowing the user to select all values from any table which seems like the user should be able to read everything and execute their own queries. If that is the case then you don't need to lockdown what that user can read. If you only want to allow users read access then get them to connect to a user that does not own the tables and grant that user only the `SELECT` privilege on the tables.*

If you want to check that the user is providing a single table name then you will need to use PL/SQL and either `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or a cursor to run some dynamic SQL (and could also use the `DBMS_ASSERT` package to assert that the user-supplied table name is a single valid value).